# Delphi TFDQuery - Filter for multiple expressions and YearOf

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to set up a filter with the actual year and month.
Database is MSSQL.

I added `DateUtils` to my uses. How can I set up the filter expression to use the `YearOf()` function?

How can I add more than one line filter expression? Is this possible?

This is working:

```pascal
with FDQuery2 do begin
  Filtered := False;
  Filter := '"Posting Year" = 2021';  //+ 'Posting month = January'
  Filtered := True;
end;
```

Unfortunately, this returns me an error:

```pascal
with FDQuery2 do begin
  Filtered := False;
  Filter := '"Posting Year" = YearOf';  
  Filtered := True;
end;
```

[image]

How can I add a second filter expression?

UPDATE: I used now a little workaround to avoid much more work due to converting `TDateTime`, etc.

```pascal
var
  YearFilter: string;

YearFilter := IntToStr(CurrentYear);
```

Comment: According to http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Date_and_Time_Support, `YearOf` requires a TDateTime as input argument but you aren't supplying one.  Best to fix that before movig on to multiple expression filtering.

Comment: yes, thanks for the hint. Can I put a variable in a filter expression? So I could try to extract it from Year of and put in a variable. Or what you suggest?

Comment: I used now a little workaround to avoid much more work due to converting TDateTime etc.

var
 YearFilter: string;

 YearFilter := IntToStr(CurrentYear);

This gives me the ability to put the result of the variable in the filter expression. But how?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the use if `YearOf` in your q.  YearOf returns a Word, whereas `Posting Year` contains a TDateTime  so you are not comparing like with like.  A rethink is needed, seems to me.  Btw there are loads of examples of FDac filter expressions around, try googling a few.

Comment: I want to filter the column "Posting Year" in my DBgrid just by year. So I converted now CurrentYear to a string.

Comment: YearOf is a Delphi function, not a database function. The way to do what you're asking depends on the DBMS you're using, which you have not mentioned at all. What database engine are you using?

Comment: I'm using MSSQL.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get the filtering now correctly.
To get the month of the year I have to declare a TDate variable.
MonthOfTheYear returns me the month as Dword - for use in a filter expression it needs converting to a string via IntToStr.

Date is the function System.SysUtils.Date.
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.Date

```
 Date1 := Date;
```

We assign Date1 variable just the actual date with System.SysUtils.Date

```
var 
   Date1: TDate;
   YearFilter, MonthFilter: string;

       with FDQuery2 do begin
         Filtered := False;

         YearFilter := IntToStr(CurrentYear);
          Date1 := Date();
         MonthFilter := IntToStr(MonthOfTheYear(Date1));

         Filter := '"Posting Year" = ' + QuotedStr(YearFilter) + ' AND ' + '"Posting Month" = ' + QuotedStr(MonthFilter);

         Filtered := True;

       end;
```

Comment: I don't see how that can work correctly except by chance.  Assuming `Date` and `Date1` are local variables, on entry to this code, Date will have a **random** value and so will Date1 when you assign Date to Date1 and so MonthFilter will have too.  Btw please don't just quote code snippets without surrounding context - is the code you quote, incl the variables all contained in a single method or what.  Also lose the habit of using "with" - it will cause you far more problems with subtle errors than it will ever save you typing-wise.

Comment: Date is not random it is the Delphi function that returns the actual date from the system.
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.Date

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you are reading/understanding your own code.  Regardless of the declaration of the Date function in SysUtils, your code includes `var  Date: TDate;` which takes precedence over `Date` in SysUtils, and your `Date` - if it is a local variable - **will have** a random value  when ` Date1 := Date` is executed.

Comment: Yes on initializing it is random but in the code, you see Date1 := Date; which assigns the actual date.

Comment: But `Date1 := Date` assigns the value of Date to Date1.  Since Date is random, so will be Date1 after the assignment.  I think you would find it would help for you to show the entire code of your filtering method, not just a snippet, as I said before.

Comment: I adapted the code snippet so that it makes more sense...